# Why do a .net form and controls not size properly on a given user's machine?

Tags: vb.net, desktop-application, screen-resolution

We received a large net desktop application from another agency to implement at our agency. It's messy, but works. It uses a midi form with forms opening inside that, and panels. We compiled and deployed in Visual Studio 2015. It's VB.

All users have Windows 7 64 Pro. For one user, when forms open, the lower portion is cut off. If restored (un maximized), the form shrinks to a tiny window in the upper left of the midi window. If borders are dragged the form will expand, but only a small portion of the form at the upper left will contain anything, as if inside a shrunken panel with scroll bars.

I changed the application so forms have a minimum size that should prevent them from shrinking down, but that doesn't work on her machine. I also changed a couple of panels to "fill" similar to adjacent panels. On other machines the application works excellent, even if display is changed to larger 150%. On the problem machine, the application only works if the display is set to smaller 100% and will not work on medium or larger. The user chooses to have larger.

I can place code on resize events and try to force everything to display correctly, but should not have to do that. The application works correctly everywhere else. Something is different about the problem machine where window metrics are not being computed properly or something similar. All machines are made from the same image and have the same drivers. I cannot see any additional software installed.

I would like to know if anyone else has seen this issue and how it was resolved.

Comment: this might sound silly, but does she have a different monitor?

Comment: Maybe because your program isn't dpi aware? Is the one user's display set to a different resolution?

Comment: resolution, some settings in ease of access center or framework dll's are different.